# Same Xpath expression returns different results

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I understand that for the below xml the xpath expression "//span[position()=1]" returns the first span element anywhere in the document:

```
<div>
<span>qty</span>
<span>price</span>
<span>time</span>
</div>
```

But when the same expression "//span[position()=1]" is used for the below XML, then it returns all the span elements instead of the first span element

```
<div>
<b><span>qty</span></b>
<b><span>price</span></b>
<b><span>time</span></b>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Because in your first example all your `span` elements reside on the same level so that they all have different positions. However in your second example each `span` resides within its own container (`<b>`) where each of them has the `position=1`, hence all the elements are returned.

To return first `span` in your second example you can use the xpath like this:

```
(//span)[1]
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexey for quick response. I want to focus more on this concept, can you please elaborate more on this or point to specific articles which explains this concept.

Comment: 8@SandeshSawant It's all about the context: *"The `position` function returns a number equal to the **context** position from the expression evaluation context."*  from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/position. The article gives also examples.